# SQL Server CE 3.5 Merge Replication

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, replication, sql-server-ce

I am working on an application that will connect to SQL Server 2005 when users are in the office, or it will connect to SQL Server CE 3.5 when users are on a laptop and out of the office.

I have been reading up on Merge Replication to keep the two in sync, but am having a hard time finding anthing from start to finish (all the documentation I have found seems to be fragmented).

Basically, I'm looking for some documention that has the whole process to set this up step-by-step.

Does anyone know of a good resource?  Has anyone done this before that can offer any guidance?

Also, since users will either be on a laptop or pc, would it be easier to use SQL Server Express instead of SQL Server CE for this type of thing when they are on their laptop?  Pros, cons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good ressource to start with is a book by Rob tiffany on the subject: http://darrenflatt.com/2009/10/31/new-book-by-rob-tiffanyenterprise-data-synchronization-with-microsoft-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-compact-35-mobile-merge-replication.aspx

It's not free but that would be the best start. He explained pretty in details how to setup merge replication. It's a pretty small book 250 pages written in BIG font with ALOT of screnshots and it's like almost pocket size. You could go through it in a day or two.

Another suggestion would be to go with Microsoft Synchronization Services, which is more a developper oriented solution. There might by more online ressource for this solution.

As to Merge Replication is more a database configuration.

Hope it helps